# Diophantine equation $3^{m}x+3^{m}-3^{m-i} 2^{i} +3^{m-i} 2^{i+s} -2^{m+s}=x 2^{m+s}$

Tags: diophantine-equations, collatz-conjecture

As part of my research and my calculations I got the following diophantine equation. I do not have much experience with the diophantine equation. Is there any known method to solve it? Any help is appreciated:

$$3^{m}x+3^{m}-3^{m-i} 2^{i} +3^{m-i} 2^{i+s} -2^{m+s}=x 2^{m+s}$$

with

$m,i,s,x\in\mathbb{N}$

Thanks.

Comment: what are you solving for? It does not look like Diophantine equation.

Comment: If you write $x+1 = y$, then the equation is equivalent with $3^{m-1} 2^i (2^s - 1) = (2^{m+s} - 3^m)y$. It clearly follows from here that $y$ is of the form $y = 2^i 3^{m-1} z$. So we are reduced into finding when $2^{m+s} - 3^m$ divides $2^s - 1$.

Comment: @J.J. Thanks. If I understand correctly, the problem has shifted now to study the Diophantine equation $\frac{2^{m+s} - 3^m}{2^s -1}=z$, z natural number. Is there any known method to solve it?

Comment: @Mark: The other way around: $\frac{2^s - 1}{2^{m+s} - 3^m} = z$. I'm not sure whether there are solutions besides $m=1$, $s=1$ and $m=2$, $s=1$. (In the second case $z$ will be negative.)

Comment: Re-asked here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669827/divisibility-of-2n-1-by-2mn-3m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered the question $$ {2^s-1\over 2^{m+s}-3^m}$$ (as formulated in @mark's comment) in the answer where @barto has linked to. There is a proof of Ray Steiner (1977) that

> the only solution is $(m,s)=(1,1)$.

*(See details in the linked [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/669827/divisibility-of-2n-1-by-2mn-3m))*