# Divisibility of $2^n - 1$ by $2^{m+n} - 3^m$.

Tags: diophantine-equations, divisibility, collatz-conjecture

For what values of $m,n$ natural, do $2^n - 1$ is divisible by $2^{m+n} - 3^m$?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Yes, sorry I have edited the question.

Comment: Hmm, it looks suspiciously similar to a formula which I've dealt with in the Collatz-discussion years ago, but I cannot yet pinpoint the fact. However this suggests to me that there might be no solution with elementary means. I'll see, whether I can come back to this later...

Comment: Essentially the same as http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/668738/diophantine-equation-3mx3m-3m-i-2i-3m-i-2is-2ms-x-2

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The question is indeed equivalent to find solutions for an 1-cycle in the Collatz-problem. Let's first rewrite your divisibility - criterion as a cofactored expression

$$2^n-1 =  (2^{n+m}-3^m) \cdot h \qquad \qquad \text{for some integer $h \ge 1$ }\tag 1$$

From the study of cycles in the Collatz-problem there is the theorem:

$ \qquad \qquad$   ***There are no solutions for (1) except $m=n=h= 1$ .***

There is a short note of Ray Steiner where he paraphrases his disproof of the possibility of a nontrivial 1-cycle in the Collatz-problem. His formula is identical except the naming of variables. He wrote me a short informal note which I adapt for the use here:

> Briefly, my 1977 proof runs as follows. I will just give the steps,
>   not the details here.
>
> 1) Any circuit for the 3x+1 problem
>      corresponds to an integer solution $(k, l, h)$ of the Diophantine equation
>      $ (2^{k+l} - 3^k)h = 2^l -1 \qquad \qquad (*)$
>
> 2) To show that the only integer solution of (*) is $(1,1,1)$
>          First, reduce this to a problem in linear forms in logarithms:
>        $$0 \lt | l/k - \log_2 3/2 | \lt 1/(k \cdot \ln 2 \cdot (2^k-1)) $$
>
> 3) This shows that if $k \gt 4$ then $l/k$ must be a convergent in the continued fraction expansion of $\log_2(3/2)$  .
>
> 4) By using a lemma of Legendre, one can prove that a partial quotient of this CF must exceed $10^{4690}$
>
> 5). Using Baker's, or Rhin's theorem one finds a reasonable upper bound for $k$ and the denominators of all convergents in this range are all smaller than $2500$.

There is a more involved discussion of this and extension from 2- up to 68-cycles done by [John Simons and Benne de Weger](http://deweger.xs4all.nl/papers/%5B35%5DSidW-3n+1-ActaArith%5B2005%5D.pdf) in the early 2000's. See the [references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Papers) which I've provided in the wikipedia-article on the [Collatz-problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture).